# How can I make my Javascript always submit properly?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, codeigniter

I have a .php file with some javascript that calls a canvas draw, upon submitting the form will upload the canvas draw image and it will submit SQL data to a database. 100% of the time the SQL data will be uploaded. My problem is the javascript will not always upload. My browser is mobile safari on an iPad. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Below is the file that captures the image. It then uploads it to upload_data.php. I am using the codeigniter framework.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Trailer Draw</title>

 <script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.5.0.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
     initialize();
  });


  // works out the X, Y position of the click inside the canvas from the X, Y     position on the page
  function getPosition(mouseEvent, sigCanvas) {
     var x, y;
     if (mouseEvent.pageX != undefined && mouseEvent.pageY != undefined) {
        x = mouseEvent.pageX;
        y = mouseEvent.pageY;
     } else {
        x = mouseEvent.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +  document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        y = mouseEvent.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +  document.documentElement.scrollTop;
     }

     return { X: x - sigCanvas.offsetLeft, Y: y - sigCanvas.offsetTop };
  }

  function initialize(canvas, context, onload) {
     // get references to the canvas element as well as the 2D drawing context
     var sigCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasSignature");
     var context = sigCanvas.getContext("2d");
     context.strokeStyle = 'red';
     make_base();

  function make_base(){
     base_image = new Image();
     base_image.src = '/inc/img/inspection/trailer.png';
     base_image.onload = function(){
     context.drawImage(base_image, 2, 100);

      }
    }

     // This will be defined for the iPad
     var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

     if (is_touch_device) {
        // create a drawer which tracks touch movements
        var drawer = {
           isDrawing: false,
           touchstart: function (coors) {
              context.beginPath();
              context.moveTo(coors.x, coors.y);
              this.isDrawing = true;
           },
           touchmove: function (coors) {
              if (this.isDrawing) {
                 context.lineTo(coors.x, coors.y);
                 context.stroke();
              }
           },
           touchend: function (coors) {
              if (this.isDrawing) {
                 this.touchmove(coors);
                 this.isDrawing = false;
              }
           }
        };

        // create a function to pass touch events and coordinates to drawer
        function draw(event) {

           // get the touch coordinates.  Using the first touch in case of  multi-touch
           var coors = {
              x: event.targetTouches[0].pageX,
              y: event.targetTouches[0].pageY
           };

           // Now we need to get the offset of the canvas location
           var obj = sigCanvas;

           if (obj.offsetParent) {
              // Every time we find a new object, we add its offsetLeft and offsetTop to curleft and curtop.
              do {
                 coors.x -= obj.offsetLeft;
                 coors.y -= obj.offsetTop;
              }
              // The while loop can be "while (obj = obj.offsetParent)" only, which does return null
              // when null is passed back, but that creates a warning in some editors (i.e. VS2010).
              while ((obj = obj.offsetParent) != null);
           }

           // pass the coordinates to the appropriate handler
           drawer[event.type](coors);
        }


        // attach the touchstart, touchmove, touchend event listeners.
        sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchstart', draw, false);
        sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw, false);
        sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchend', draw, false);

        // prevent elastic scrolling
        sigCanvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
        }, false); 
     }
     else {

        // start drawing when the mousedown event fires, and attach handlers to
        // draw a line to wherever the mouse moves to
        $("#canvasSignature").mousedown(function (mouseEvent) {
           var position = getPosition(mouseEvent, sigCanvas);

           context.moveTo(position.X, position.Y);
           context.beginPath();

           // attach event handlers
           $(this).mousemove(function (mouseEvent) {
              drawLine(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);
           }).mouseup(function (mouseEvent) {
              finishDrawing(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);
           }).mouseout(function (mouseEvent) {
              finishDrawing(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);
           });
        });

     }
  }


  // draws a line to the x and y coordinates of the mouse event inside
  // the specified element using the specified context
  function drawLine(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context) {

     var position = getPosition(mouseEvent, sigCanvas);

     context.lineTo(position.X, position.Y);
     context.stroke();
  }

  // draws a line from the last coordiantes in the path to the finishing
  // coordinates and unbind any event handlers which need to be preceded
  // by the mouse down event
  function finishDrawing(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context) {
     // draw the line to the finishing coordinates
     drawLine(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);

     context.closePath();

     // unbind any events which could draw
     $(sigCanvas).unbind("mousemove")
                 .unbind("mouseup")
                 .unbind("mouseout");
      }
   </script>
   <div>

    </div>

    <script>
        function uploadEx() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasSignature");
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById('hidden_data').value = dataURL;
            var fd = new FormData(document.forms["form"]);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/inc/img/inspection/upload_data.php', true);

            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                    console.log(percentComplete + '% uploaded');
                  //alert('Succesfully uploaded');
                }
            };

            xhr.onload = function() {

            };
            xhr.send(fd);

            return false;
        };
        </script>

        </head>
        <style>
        input {
         margin-left: 200cm;
         }

         </style>

        <body>
        <h1>Trailer Inspection</h1>

        <div id="canvasDiv" align="center">
        <!-- It's bad practice (to me) to put your CSS here.  I'd recommend    the use of a CSS file! -->
  <canvas id="canvasSignature" width="955px" height="465px" style="border:2px  solid #000000;"></canvas>


    </div>
    <p><h2></h2></p>
    <p><h4></h4></p>

    <?php if( !empty($table)): ?>
    <p><h3></h3></p>
    <?php if(is_array($table)): ?>
    <?php foreach($table as $h1 => $t1): ?>
    <?php if( !is_int($h1)): ?>
    <p><h3><?php echo $h1; ?></h3></p>
    <?php else: ?>
    <br />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(is_array($t1)): ?>
    <?php foreach($t1 as $h2 => $t2): ?>
      <?php if( !is_int($h2)): ?>
        <p><h4><?php echo $h2; ?></h4></p>
      <?php else: ?>
        <br />
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php echo $t2; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $t1; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $table;?>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>



    <br />



    <?php if( !function_exists('form_open')): ?>
    <?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
    <?php endif;?>

                                                                                      <form onsubmit="uploadEx();" name="form" id="form" accept-charset="utf-8"  method="post">
              <input name="hidden_data" id="hidden_data" type="hidden" />
              <?php $this->load->helper('string');?>
              <?php $number = random_string('unique');?>
              <input name="sub_id" id="sub_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $number; ?>"/> 

              <div>

  <?php if( !empty($options1) AND !empty($label_display1) AND   !empty($field_name1)): ?>
  <?php echo form_label($label_display1.":",$field_name1); ?>
  <?php echo form_dropdown($field_name1,$options1)?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php echo form_label('Carrier Code','car_code'); ?>
  <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'car_code','type'=>'text')); ?>

  <?php echo form_label('Trailer Number','trlr_num'); ?>
  <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'trlr_num','type'=>'text')); ?>

  <?php echo form_label('Truck Number','truck_num'); ?>
  <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'truck_num','type'=>'text')); ?>

  <?php echo form_label('Temp','temp'); ?>
  <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'temp','type'=>'text')); ?>

  <?php if( !empty($options) AND !empty($label_display) AND  !empty($field_name)): ?>
  <?php echo form_label($label_display.":",$field_name); ?>
  <?php echo form_dropdown($field_name,$options)?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php echo form_label('License Plate','lic_plate'); ?>
  <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'lic_plate','type'=>'text')); ?>

  <?php echo form_label('Seal','seal'); ?>
  <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'seal','type'=>'text')); ?>

  <?php echo form_label('STN/Delivery Note','del_note'); ?>
  <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'del_note','type'=>'text')); ?>

  <?php echo form_label('Ship Number','ship_num'); ?>
  <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'ship_num','type'=>'text')); ?>

  <input type="hidden" name="draw_num" id="draw_num" value="<?php echo  $number; ?>" />

  <?php echo form_label('Driver Name','driver_name'); ?>
  <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'driver_name','type'=>'text')); ?>

  <?php echo form_label('Check if Live','live_drop'); ?>
  <?php echo  form_checkbox(array('name'=>'live_drop','type'=>'checkbox','value'=>'1')); ?>


  <?php echo form_label('Check if Damaged','damaged'); ?>
  <?php echo form_checkbox(array('name'=>'damaged','type'=>'checkbox','value'=>'1')); ?>


  <?php echo form_label('Comment','comment'); ?>
  <textarea class="txtarea" style="height:100px; width:350px;" rows="3" name="comment" Id="comment" value=""> </textarea>

  <?php echo form_fieldset_close(); ?>

   </div>
  </br>
 </br>

 <input align="center" type ="submit" name="submit" onclick="uploadEx();">   </input>
</br>
</br>
</form>





</body>

</html>
```

Below is my upload_data.php

```
<?php
$upload_dir = "upload/";
$img = $_POST['hidden_data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$id = $_POST['sub_id'];
$file = $upload_dir . $id . ".png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

Comment: please only post code relevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once that has a onsubmit event in the form, you didn't need to make a second calling in the submit button.
In this situation, the onclick event in the submit button can be fired before the onsubmit event causing a fault.

---

Furthermore, you can try make the XMLHttpRequest as synchronous in order to avoid disordered execution of your script sequence by changing the following parameter:

Instead:

```
xhr.open('POST', '/inc/img/inspection/upload_data.php', true);
```

Change to:

```
xhr.open('POST', '/inc/img/inspection/upload_data.php', false);
```

Comment: I removed the onclick event in my submit button and I submitted quite a few more. One of them failed to upload the image but the SQL data uploaded.

Comment: I will surely try this. Thank you.

Comment: You know, I think the XMLHttpRequest issue combined with the onsubmit button may have been my issue. With just changing the onsubmit issue, they would intermittently go through. After changing it to false it appears they all go through. Is it correct in saying that by changing it to false the client waits for a response from the server before executing anything?

Comment: Yes, supposing in a script with three lines where the second is the open() method, in the asynchronous mode, the JS will execute the first and second line and immediately the third without awaiting its response. During of the transfer, the JS will executing the callbacks you have attached on it, updating your variables, however it is too late once the third line already was executed using the wrong values. In the synchronous mode, the script will freeze your application in the second line awaiting for the server transfer in order to provide the updated values for the third line.

Answer (score 0):

You return false from the function, but you do not have a return in the onclick

```
<input align="center" type ="submit" name="submit" onclick="uploadEx();">
```

needs to be

```
<input align="center" type ="submit" name="submit" onclick="return uploadEx();">
```

Comment: If I do onclick="return uploadEx();" then I can't select the submit button. I can "click" it but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: It should run the function. You can not make an asynchronous Ajax call and submit a form at the same time. You can call submit when the Ajax call completes.